# How to access controls in an iframe using WatiN?

Tags: c#, dom, iframe, dynamic, watin

I am trying to access a checkbox within an iframe, using `WatiN` in C#.

The documentation suggests using this:

`var frame = browser.Frame(frameId);`

However, I have tried that format, like this:

```
var edUsrFrame = browser.Frame(Find.ByName ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WindowManager1359542712913"));
```

However, I can't figure out how to access the element nested on that frame (a checkbox).

Is the issue that the iframe is using a dynamic name? I've tried directly accessing the checkbox, but again, no success.

Thank you.

Comment: First, Is it in same domain?

Answer (score 2):

You treat a frame just like you would a "top level" browser when you want to access items inside the frame.

To click a checkbox:

```
var myFrame = browser.Frame(Find.bywhatever());  //Gets the frame
myFrame.CheckBox(Find.ByName("checkboxnamehere")).Click();
```

Or more simply:

```
browser.Frame(Find.Bywhatever(...)).CheckBox(Find.ByWhatever(...)).Click();
```

If the frame is using a dynamic name that is changing each time the page loads, instead of finding by name, find by a regular expression, or by index, or by something that identifies that frame succinctly.  Bottom line:  If the name changes page load to page load, you can't use name.

Comment: I have no success with that strategy yet.

Comment: The index isn't suitable, and regex isn't working as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

browser.Frame(Find.ByName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WindowManager1359542712913")).CheckBox(Find.ById("abc")).Click();

Comment: http://watin.org/documentation/element-class-mapping-table/ - suggests Find.ByName - I can't find the documentation on the available methods for a frame?

Comment: Are you able to use something other than name though? Or dynamic IDs?

Comment: Could you try to provide a little more of an explanation to your answer?